# how to add parameters with Add handler vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want to add Parameters With Add Handler. i will Attach My code ...

```
AddHandler timer1.Tick, AddressOf timer1_Tick(sender ,e)
```

how to pass Parameter with event Click timer1_Tick ? i want to send  control arguments in vb.net

Comment: Those parameter will be provided by the control which raises the event and you can not use them when adding handler.

Comment: You can't send arguments because an event is not invoked immediately, it's not a method call. You could use fields or properties or pass arguments where you raise the event..

Comment: Right now, the way it's written, it will get the addressof of the return value of timer1_Tick(sender, e)

Comment: What is the task that requires extending the event handler with additional arguments? There must be a property way to accomplish your task, so it makes sense to describe it. Perhaps, all you need is to use instance variables to pass an appropriate state to the timer1_Tick method.